# I can't controll the setting time in AlarmManager when restart APP

Tags: android

I want to set the notification for custom time , i take a reference from http://www.singhajit.com/schedule-local-notification-in-android/

I add some manifest code which is for when the device reboot.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
    package="com.example.user.testcounddown">

    <!-- for reboot----------------------  -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <!-- for reboot---------------------  -->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

The problem is when i reboot my device , the notification shows immediately , not after about 300esc  `cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 300);`

here is my MainActivity code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
        notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");


        PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 300);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), broadcast);//for API<=18

}
```

my receiver code:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

        Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle("Demo App Notification")
                .setContentText("New Notification From Demo App..")
                .setTicker("New Message Alert!")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
}
```

How do i let the notification shows in the right time when device reboot ?

```
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 300);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,thanks.

Comment: I find the way now.